# SQL Server 2014 - Windows could not start SQL server on local computer

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014, reinstall

I have an AWS instance, on which SQL Server 2014 has been running for more than 3 years.

But a few days ago, suddenly the SQL Server stopped running.

I checked the server and tried to start SQL Server service from services, from SQL Server Configuration Manager etc. but I'm not able to start the server and got following error:

[image: Windows could not start SQL server on local computer - please click for image]

So I checked event viewer entries and I found these two errors:

[image: please click for image]

[image: please click for image]

I started some research work over web to overcome on this issue and I found that I can start SQL service using below command using T902:

```
net start MSSQL$REVCORD /T902
```

And SQL Server service started successfully.

But I want to make SQL Server / services back to normal as before so I can start / stop services normally.

I found on web that this cause is due to corruption in `master` SQL Server database, I don't have backup of `master` SQL Server database so I cannot restore it back.

I checked multiple threads over web and tried multiple things to overcome this issue but no luck.

So finally I decided to reinstall/recover SQL Server 2014, but I am getting another error while reinstalling:

[image: please click for image]

[image: please click for image]

Based on finding over web, all threads showing that I have to uninstall and reinstall SQL Server to make it normal again.

Please help! It's a live server with multiple calls continously so I cannot uninstall/reinstall SQL Server there due to possible data loss.

Comment: You say you are using SQL 2014 but the error installing the service pack says SQL 2012 Service Pack 1.   Are you trying to install 2012 service pack one over SQL 2014?

Comment: What errors do you have in SQL log file when running the service without the 902 trace flag? Can you show us the errors?

Comment: Fred do not worry about image showing 2012, I took similar image from web because I don't have actual image of it.

Comment: @DenisRubashkin With 902 its running normally, still let me know if there might be logs and from where I can found those logs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first thing:

```
select * from sys.sysmessages where error = 5833
```

The message:

> The affinity mask specified is greater than the number of CPUs supported or licensed on this edition of SQL Server.

Check your edition, and fix the affinity mask so that the number of CPUs satisfy the number which is supported by your edition.
You can fix it in SSMS on the **Processors** tab in your server properties, or using `sp_configure`

Comment: Great !! Its working normally now. but please confirm one thing,

There were Automatically set processor affinity mask for all processors checked before which I unchecked and select all CPUs manually there and tried starting service and its getting start normally now. 

Please let me know if anything wrong with this.

Comment: One more thing, I reverted above changes to cross check but still its working fine normally now. Strange !!

Comment: Your error occured after setting up some CU or Servce Pack. Obviously, inside the update scripts was a check, and it make the error happened. You started your server successfully, the update scripts were applied, that's why you could return the previous setting. I guess next time you will be setting up the next CU you will get the same error.